# How to get gateway address when subnetting?

Tags: ip-address, gateway, subnet

I have to subnet a network from a single class C IP address.

I have figured out the subnet mask and the broadcast address (I'm using subnet mask /28) but don't understand how to get the gateway address.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: The gateway address is not discoverable; it does not even have to be within the IP range and netmask of your IP!

Comment: so if i just put any answer down then its right? the question specifically asks me for the gateway address...this is why i was so confused coz i thought it was random too

Comment: Gateway addresses, usually called the `default gateway`, are arbitrarily assigned.  In my networks they are either numbered at the bottom (+1) or the top (-1) of the range.  For example, in network 10.10.10.0/255.255.255.0, my gateway address is either 10.10.10.1, or 10.10.10.254.  Broadcast is always at the top end of the range, 10.10.10.255.

Comment: @Joe: Surely only if there is super or multi-netting going on? However, you can't say that a subnet's gateway address is outside of the subnet, it either has one or doesn't.

Comment: @MattH: also if the gateway is on the same physical switch segment, it will will be routable.  A number of ISPs do/did this especially on point-to-point IPs.

Answer (score 7):

If subnet mask is 255.255.255.248 then number of masked bit will be 5, hence number of subnets = 2. The power number of masked bits = 2 the power 5 = 32 subnets, and the number of hosts per subnets = 2. The power (unmasked bit or 32- total number of network bits) = 2 the power (32-29) = 8 host/subnet.

Hence:

- 1) IP's in subnet-1 will be from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.1.7
  where 192.168.1.0 will be subnet id and 192.168.1.7 will be broadcast id.
- 2) IP's in subnet-2 will be from 192.168.1.8 to 192.168.1.15

and so on............

- 32) IP's in subnet-32 will be from 192.168.1.248 to 192.168.1.255.....

The gateway is only one for a network i.e. the first IP address of that network.

Answer (score 5):

This post is almost 8 years old, but in case someone wanders across this, I wanted to fix a few issues with the top voted comment. I would've commented directly, but I literally just started this account, so I don't have the authority to do that.

1. A subnet mask of /28 would be 255.255.255.240, not 248, not 248.
2. Having 32 subnets with 8 hosts per subnet is impossible with the given mask.

The purpose of the mask is that is shows which bits within a network can and can't change. 240 in binary = 1111 0000. This means the first 4 msb in the last value cannot change AND be in the same network.

So let's say your network address is 192.168.1.0/28. Write the last decimal value (0) out in binary with 8 bits. 0000 0000. Since 240 comes out to 1111 0000, the first 4 bits must remain unchanged in order to be subnets on the same network.

From here, subnets and hosts are determined by the last 4 bits. You can have 2 subnets with 6 hosts/subnet or 4 subnets with 2 hosts/subnet. Say you're going with the first option. The last decimal in the address (0) has this notation. MMMM SHHH

- M is Masked bits which can't change in network.
- S is Subnet ID, which determines the subnet
- H is Host ID, which determines the hosts.

Looking at some values with the mask

- Mask 240  = 1111 0000
- Binary 0  = 0000 0000
- Binary 15 = 0000 1111
- Binary 16 = 0001 0000

As we see, binary 16 would change a bit within the mask. Once a bit covered by the mask is changed, you're in a different network.

So the final breakdown would be

1) IP's in subnet-1 = 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.6 where 192.168.1.0 will be subnet id and 192.168.1.7 will be broadcast id.

2) IP's in subnet-2 = 192.168.1.9 to 192.168.1.14 where 192.168.1.8 will be subnet id and 192.168.1.15 will be broadcast id.

Once again, I don't expect much traction on an 8 year old post, but if someone happens across this like I did, I don't want them to get confused with the wrong information.

Comment: the question is about gateway and you dont have that word a single time in your answer. What exactly is the gateway adress here?

Answer (score 1):

The gateway address is arbitrary in IPv4. Configured statically or dynamically on each host.

"Class C" is obsolete terminology and not correct.

Comment: does that mean for the answer i just pick any ip address in that range? (that isnt the network add. or the broadcast add.)

Comment: Normally the lowest or highest host address, but only by convention.

Answer (score 0):

In a broadcast network, any IP address in the subnet's usable range can be a gateway (and there can be multiple gateways too). It is only by convention that either the first or last usable addresses are typically chosen nowadays.

The gateway for a network/subnet has to be (physically) setup on a network and each host on that network has to be made aware of that gateway - both are setup by the administrator and are picked from an arbitrary IP address in the subnet. Hosts are made aware of the gateway address(es) either by DHCP/Static addressing or by a route advertisement (through a routing protocol like RIP or OSPF, etc).

Answer (score 0):

The last three contributors are correct and for more reference to folks who are new, see at least https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc950 "Internet Standard Subnetting Procedure"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).